# hOW to set the image from URL without any blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am uploading the image from the ImagePicker and once the image is upload on the server I show it from URL. So from local image to URL image, there comes a blink, which I want to avoid but I am unable to fix it.

I am adding the code below:

```
- (void)setDataOnCell:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self.messageTimeLabel.text = [CommonUtils checkForNUllValue:[dict valueForKey:@"msg_time"]];
    if (![[CommonUtils checkForNUllValue:[dict valueForKey:@"msg_status"]] isEqualToString:@"Read"]) {
        self.messageTickImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_delivered_icon"];
        self.messageStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:166.0f/255.0f green:166.0f/255.0f blue:166.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    }
    else {
        self.messageTickImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_read_icon"];
        self.messageStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0f/255.0f green:223.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    }
    self.messageStatusLabel.text = [CommonUtils checkForNUllValue:[dict valueForKey:@"msg_status"]];
    
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"attachment_type"]] isEqualToString:@"local_img"]){
        self.messageImageview.image = [dict valueForKey:@"attachment"];
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                       ^{
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"attachment"]]]];
            NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            //This is your completion handler
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData];
                self.messageImageview.image = image;
            });
        });
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_sync`? Also try adding the image change to an animation block.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to set a default image on this image view after that you call image by url and set on this

```
NSOperationQueue *queueThumbnl = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queueThumbnl setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount];
    [queueThumbnl addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Background work
              NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"attachment"]]]];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData];
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.messageImageview, @"messageImageview", urlData, @"imageData", nil];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mainThreadUIUpdate:) withObject:dict waitUntilDone:YES];
          //  [self updateThumbnailOnMainThread:anItem setImageTo:cell];
        }];


-(void)mainThreadUIUpdate:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    UIImageView *messge = [dict objectForKey:@"messageImageview"];
    UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];
    [messge.imageView setImage:image];
    [cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: Actually I am setting the default image at first then I set the image from URL, so the conversion from Default to URL makes it blink which I want to avoid. I'll check your answer and let you know the output. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: add faded animation when you change image its seem clear